# Issue while loading the direct route of angular app deployed on nginx, cloudRun@GCP

Tags: angular, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy my angular app on nginx as container on GCP cloud run. The app is working fine, if I load the app via home page and navigate. But if I try to load an app route directly. It fails with mime error as below. I have allowed mime.types in nginx and added on nginx.conf file. I have also added below location tag in to rewrite to index.html

```
    runtime.46fb68c434174d9b.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
polyfills.938d3d63ac22b057.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
main.89919748d2009153.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec


location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  index index.html index.htm Default.htm;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the problem. The problem was I was keeping the basehref as ./ and output was to --output-path=/dist/out while building. I correct it and it started working....